# How to store the time of creation of record using a trigger/otherwise in Mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to automatically store `request_time` as the current time when keyword is updated.

Here's a sample table:

```
id     request_time           keyword
1      2011-02-03 8:00:08     free
```

On inserting `free`, `request_time` should be set to `NOW();`.

Here's the trigger i have but it doesnt work:

```
delimiter //
create trigger ai_update_userinput after update on user_input 
for each row begin update user_input
set request_time = NOW(); end//
```

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timestamp columns already provide this functionality when they have `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` set. See [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html).

Answer (score 1):

That should be possible with a timestamp column, even without a trigger. Take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html in particular the example for the 'on update' clause for the column spec in the table creation.

Comment: Thanks. I see. I need to change the request_time column to be of type TIMESTAMP then use 'on update,